# Managing counters in c++ using CQL prepared queries

Tags: c++, cassandra, cql

Reposting actual code

```
    // cassandra is a connected org::apache::cassandra::CassandraClient
// statement is a CqlPreparedResult
// result is a CqlResult
// CF declaration is:
/*
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY xp (
  cid ascii PRIMARY KEY,
  exp4 counter,
  exp2 counter,
  exp3 counter,
  exp1 counter
) WITH
  comment='' AND
  comparator=text AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  default_validation=counter AND
  min_compaction_threshold=4 AND
  max_compaction_threshold=32 AND
  replicate_on_write=True AND
  compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
  compression_parameters:sstable_compression='org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor';
 */
std::vector<std::string> values;
values.resize(2);
values[0]="1";
values[1]="103";
cassandra->prepare_cql_query(statement,"update xp set exp2 = exp2 + ? where cid=?",Compression::NONE);
int32_t handle=statement.itemId;
try {
    cassandra->execute_prepared_cql_query(result,handle,values);
}
catch(InvalidRequestException &e) {
    cout << __LINE__ << " " << e.why << " "<< e.what() << endl;
}
// throws '?' is an invalid value, should be a long.
values.resize(1);
values[0]="103";
cassandra->prepare_cql_query(statement,"update xp set exp2 = exp2 + 1 where cid=?",Compression::NONE);
handle=statement.itemId;
cassandra->execute_prepared_cql_query(result,handle,values);
//works
```

So looks like the issue is in the fact we cant pass binary data.
I tried to pass in a string containing the actual representation of a long, with no success.
Same issue when I read data from, but I think i can manage it (scanning the returned string and converting it one byte at a time as a last resort)

Is anyone using counters, c++ and cql with success?

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to pass binary data, so I'm not sure why you're asking about that. And that's appropriate- you shouldn't be trying to pass binary data. A couple obvious problems: `prepare_cql_query` takes a CqlPreparedResult reference, not CqlResult, and your `execute_prepared_cql_query` should be using `stm.itemId`, not `result.itemId`.

Comment: Yep you spotted a typo, but the issue remains. 
The issue is I CANT pass binary data, i only can pass strings to execute_prepared_query, BUT looks like, for counters, it needs long (exception '?' is an invalid value, should be a long values).
Did I succed in explainig it?

Comment: I don't think so. Have you actually tried running this code itself, as opposed to the code it was adapted from? This should work, as far as I can see. And no, you really don't need to send binary data; when it says it wants a long, it means in ascii-decimal form. It thinks that you've given it the string "?" as the parameter, which suggests to me that your real code might be buggy.

Comment: Apologies- I was totally wrong here. Parameters to prepared queries *should* be binary. I actually even wrote that part of the Python cql driver, but I've used CQL through a driver for so long that I'd forgotten the protocol.

Comment: I suppose my example was not good enough because I extrapolated id from my wrapper... Now I will repost it as pure Cassandra rows (and YES, I actually ran that code)

Answer (score 0):

The long value should be encoded as a big-endian 64-bit integer. So try:

```
values[0] = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x64";
```

If you're going to go on using CQL without a driver, you'll need lots of marshalling/unmarshalling routines to cover this sort of thing.

Comment: Do you know about a C++ driver? I dont :(

Comment: Already tried it :) Doesnt work, same result. Looks like a flaw in thrift interface in CQL. The bad thing is CQL itself happily manage the marshalling because if I use a literal in query for the increment value it works fine. SO i think I will resort to string managemente and will live without compiled query for insert.

Comment: No, I don't know about a driver yet. Would be nice, in case you decide to write one :^). I don't think this is a flaw in Cassandra's CQL interface, since this same set of thrift calls and values works fine in Python over the raw thrift interface. But yes, using a literal value avoids client-side marshalling altogether (Cassandra's CQL parser takes care of it) so if that meets your needs, go for it.

Comment: I said flaw in thrift interface , not in CQL interface :). But is not something I think can be circumvented easily. In python you have better mileage because Python is not strongly typed as c++. And seeing https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2478 I think we probably should wait a bit more before writing a c++ driver for Cassandra :)

Comment: Oh, and, by the way: thank you for your time. I do really appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

Well, i discovered I was missing to fulfill the correct binary encoding.
Using this function to convert my longs to a string, i succeeded in using prepared queries

```
string to_counter(const long value) {
    union  {
        long    v;
        char    cc[8];
    } xx;
    xx.v=value;
    string r;
    r.assign(xx.cc,8);
    reverse(r.begin(),r.end());
    return r;
}
```

and it's companion

```
long from_counter(const string& value) {
    union  {
        long    v;
        char    cc[8];
    } xx;
    for (size_t i=0; i < 8;++i) {
        xx.cc[7-i]=value.at(i);
    }
    return xx.v;
}
```

I am quite sure this code could be improved, any suggestino will be welcomed :)